# CSS: Header Strip Not Filling the width of the browser

Tags: html, css

Have a problem trying to have a header tab strip occupy the entire width of the browser.  Below is the code.  When the page is viewed in a browser, I see a horizaontal scroll bar for the browser, so, when you scroll over to the right, the bluish tab cuts out, revealing the white background.

How can I have this header tab expand when scrolled over too?

THanks.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body, div { margin: 0;  padding: 0; }
    html, body,form, #wrapper, #left, #right { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
    #wrapper { margin-left: 10px;overflow: hidden; width: 100%;  }
    #left { background: yellow; float: left; width: 360px; }
    #right { background: grey; margin-left: 360px; }
  </style>

  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabstrip" style="height: 25px; background-color: #63a3c7; color: White;">
  </div>


  <form id="form1" runat="server">  

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="left">
      Left
    </div>

    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: set `margin-left: 0;` for #wrapper

Comment: Add to your tabstrip style width: 100%; display: block; or float: left; clear: both; instead of display: block;

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from the `margin-left: 10px;` on your `#wrapper`. Remove it and the problem goes away.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fx9EN/)**

If for some reason you need that bit of margin there, put it on the form instead.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://jsbin.com/eyinon/1/edit). I removed the wrapper width 100%.

```
#wrapper { margin-left: 10px;overflow: hidden; }
```

Hope this helps!